# Kontsevich's A-infty cohomology classes of the moduli space of curves

Tags: homotopy-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, cohomology, moduli-spaces

In his paper "Feynman diagrams and low-dimensional topology," Kontsevich attaches to each $A_\infty$ algebra a cohomology class (with complex coefficients) on the moduli space of smooth, complex curves of genus g with n marked points.

He does this by noting that the moduli space of ribbon graphs with metric (where each vertex has degree at least 3) of genus g and n boundary components, is isomorphic to the moduli space of curves above. He uses the given $A_\infty$ algebra to produce a partition function $Z(\Gamma)$ for a ribbon graph $\Gamma$.
Finally, he says that $\sum_\Gamma{Z(\Gamma).\Gamma}$ is a closed cochain, and that it is closed "due to the higher associativity conditions on the algebra."
Would someone be able to explain why 1. the cochain is closed; 2. why the sum is finite; 3. why this gives you a cochain rather than a chain?

I'm tried several of the references and tried to work it out myself but I can't see what Kontsevich is saying here. (I am aware that to answer this question, one probably needs to already be aware of Kontsevich's idea - and I'm hoping someone here is.)

In particular, I've looked at Harer's "The cohomology of the moduli of curves" to understand the ribbon graph moduli isomorphism as Kontsevich mentions this as an "exposition" of the result (to not much success). I've looked at Kontsevich's "Notes on $A_\infty$-algebras, $A_\infty$-categories, and noncommutative geometry," but this is even more incomprehensible to me (since he vastly generalizes the above construction). I've also looked at various papers referenced in Kontsevich's paper.